# How can I make the image show as result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a rock paper scissors game & I want the image to show as a result when the user makes a selection. For example, if i choose paper and the computer chooses rock, i want the rock image to display along with the 'lose' statement

I tried putting the images outside the folder to see if that worked but it didn't.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="score">
        <p>You:0</p>
        <p>Computer:0</p>
    </div>
     <div class="user-choices">
        <img id='rock'class='choice' src="rock.png">
        <img id='paper'class='choice' src="paper.png">
        <img id='scissors'class='choice' src="scissors.png">
   </div>
    <div class='result'>
        <div class="cpu-result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
<style>
.result img {
height: 10rem;
 }

.result{
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function cpuChoice() {
        const rand = Math.random()
        if (rand > .34) {
            return 'paper'
        } else if (rand <= .67) {
            return 'rock'
        } else {
            return 'scissors'
        }
    }

    function showWinner(winner,computerPick) {
        if (winner === 'player') {
            scoreboard.player++;
            cpuResult.innerHTML = `<h2>Win!</h2>
            <img class='cpu-result' src='${computerPick}.png>' `
        } else if (winner === 'computer') {
            scoreboard.computer++;
            cpuResult.innerHTML = `<h2>Lose!</h2>
            <img class='cpu-result' src='${computerPick}.png>'`
        } else {
            cpuResult.innerHTML = `<h2>Draw!</h2>
            <img class'cpu-result' src='${computerPick}.png>' `
        }
        score.innerHTML = `
        <p>Player:${scoreboard.player}</p>
        <p>Computer: ${scoreboard.computer}</p>
        `
        result.style.display ='block'/
    }

    choices.forEach(choices => choices.addEventListener('click', play))
</script>
```

I want the image to display along with the win lose or draw message.

Comment: are you keen on using jQuery?

Comment: change your code from `<img class='cpu-result' src='${computerPick}.png>' ` to `<img class='cpu-result' src='/${computerPick}.png>' `

Comment: no im not familiar with jQuery & i tried the forward /${computerPick}.png and it didnt show

Comment: You just need to add the right path as a prefix in your img src.

Comment: Please check your code again, there are some issues in your code ex: missing '='. Try this <img class='cpu-result' src='../${computerPick}.png'>`

Comment: There's a flaw in your CPU choice logic. If rand is greater than .34, return paper. So anything over .34 is paper. You only move to the elseif when rand is .34 or less. If rand is .34 or less, it always satisfies the next condition. You'll never hit scissors.

Comment: Browser's DevTools is your best friend. use it and check for errors.

Comment: What is the content of the variable computerpick. Does it work if you enter the path manually and with full path (http://...)

Comment: I tried changing the path and choosing the correct one. I have the images on the front page of the folder. I also changed the logic for Cpuchoice so that it would not return paper if it was >.34. The content of computerpick is based on the function cpuChoice so whether it returns rock paper or scissors.

Comment: Does it work now? Is the code above complete? I don't find the play method and where do you instantiate the object choices? Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: Yes it does work. The problem was that I had  closing quote outside of the src link. It was a rookie mistake and I should've looked at my code carefully.